# What is a Lagrange-type function

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I want to know what is the exact definition of Lagrange-type function.

For example i have the problem $$\min f_0(x)\;\;\text{ s.t } h_i(x)=0 ,\; g_j(x)\leq0$$
where $i=1,2\ldots,m$ and $j=1,2,\ldots,r$, and $f_0,h_i,g_j:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$

and we can consider this Lagrange function
$$L(x,\theta,\mu)=f_0(x)+\sum_{i=1}^m\theta_ih_i(x)+\sum_{j=1}^r\mu_jg_j(x)$$

but I have seen that also we can also consider the augmented Lagrangian.

I have thought about this definition as:
A Lagrange-type function is a function that satisfies certain properties. But what are those properties?
Or a function is a Lagrange-type function if it has a certain structure ,(for example a cuadratic form has the structure $x^TAx$, where $A$ is a symmetric matrix), but what is this structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A Lagrange-type function is the Lagrangian of a certain constrained optimization problem**.

Consider for example the following problem:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
\min f(x) \quad \mbox{s.t. } g(x) = 0, h(x) \le 0.\tag{1}
\end{equation}
The function $L(x,\lambda,\mu) = f(x) + \lambda g(x) + \mu h(x)$ (with $\mu \ge 0$) is a Lagrange-type function because it is the Lagrangian of problem \eqref{eq:1}.

Is $L(x,\lambda,\mu,\rho) = f(x) + \lambda g(x) + \mu h(x) + \rho(g(x))^2$ (known as the augmented Lagrangian of \eqref{eq:1}) a Lagrangian-type function? Yes it is, because it is the Lagrangian of the following problem (that is equivalent to \eqref{eq:1}):
\begin{equation}\label{eq:2}
\min f(x) \quad \mbox{s.t. } g(x) = 0, (g(x))^2 = 0, h(x) \le 0.\tag{2}
\end{equation}

Same for
\begin{align}
L(x,\lambda,\mu,\rho,\alpha,\beta) = &f(x) + \lambda g(x) + \mu h(x)\\
&
+\rho(g(x))^2 + \alpha\sin(g(x)) + \beta(\cos(g(x)) - 1)
\end{align}
or
\begin{align}
L(x,\lambda,\mu,\rho,\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta) = &\exp(f(x)) + \lambda g(x) + \mu h(x) \\
&+\rho(g(x))^2 + \alpha\sin(g(x)) + \beta(\cos(g(x)) - 1) \\
&-\gamma (h(x))^2 + \delta (h(x))^3,
\end{align}
where $\mu,\gamma, \delta\ge 0$. (Try to find the problems for which these are Lagrangians.)

Comment: a question, only with the equality constraints I can take functions and add them, right? or  can I also do it with those that are in the unequally constraints.

Comment: @DavidMorante Just follow the definition. When you wonder whether a function is of Lagrange-type, ask yourself: is it the Lagrangian of some constrained optimization problem? I have added a new example to the answer and I hope it will help clarify this.